# Angular: How can I get the mat-option and the visible text of the selected option together?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I want to fetch the option text of the option I selected with the option value also. What necessary changes do I need to make in my below code?

**HTML**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="changeQuestionValue($event.value)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let q of QuestionCategory">
    <mat-option *ngIf="q.isActive" [value]="q.id">{{ q.questionCategoryName }}</mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

**TS**

```
changeQuestionValue(val) {
    return this.questionValue = val;
}
```

Here in TS am only receiving the `q.id` but I also want `q.questionCategoryName`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the value property to `[value]="q"`. But if you want to store the whole value in a form control you can use the `compareWith` function to return the object selected when by the option. Just define a function to compare the objects and the pass the whole object as a value in the `mat-option`.

e.g

```
  public compareWith(obj1: Question, obj2: Question) {
    return obj1 && obj2 && obj1.id === obj2.id;
  }
```

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareWith" (selectionChange)="onChangeSelect($event.value)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let q of questionCategories">
    <mat-option *ngIf="q.isActive" [value]="q">{{ q.questionCategoryName }}</mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

Here is a live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/en-stackoverflow-62688705

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just replace `[value]="q"`

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="changeQuestionValue($event.value)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let q of QuestionCategory">
    <mat-option *ngIf="q.isActive" [value]="q">{{ q.questionCategoryName }}</mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

[value]="q"

to

value="{{q}}"